# Patching a PE executable

Tags: c, assembly, portable-executable

lets say i've loaded a PE executable into memory and suited it with dos,nt headers structures and now i want to find out its .text/code segement actual(not VA) offset+size how do i do that?
is there a win32 api for finding the .text start offset or maybe a pointer from a sturcture
that points to the start offset of that segment

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The IMAGE_FILE_HEADER and IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER have some of this information. You can retrieve them with the GetNTHeaders() function. From there, you can get the first section header with IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION (pNtHeaders). The section headers are sequential, and hold the rest of the information you are interested in. The file header contains the number of sections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [PE File Format DLL](http://www.objectmedia.ltd.uk/freeSoftware/peFileDLL.html) to get the information. Full source code provided with, non-GPL encumbered, so you can use it in your commercial project just fine.

Also available (with source) is the [PE File Explorer](http://www.objectmedia.ltd.uk/freeSoftware/peFileExplorer.html) to show you how to use the DLL.
pro